# How do I change the execution PATH of a process programatically?

Tags: c++, path, environment

I am working on a mini-shell, and am trying to set the execution path dynamically.
I am using setvar() to set the PATH and when I check it with getvar() it reads the new PATH.
Here are the two things I tried to execute:
1. I change the `PATH` to `/bin` which I know contains most system functions, but no programs can work. I can also verify that the path has been set in the environment. I execute the commands using `execvp()`
2. I then used `extern char** environ` to get the environment and pass it into `execvpe()` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure the program is in `/bin`? Most non-system-critical programs are in `/usr/bin` on most systems.

Comment: Yes, I also changed it to a folder I knew had executables in it and it still couldn't find them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using `istringstream` to manually search the PATH and then use that to execute the process:

```
string dir;
string path = get_var("PATH");
istringstream search(path);
while(search.good()) {
    getline(search, dir, ':');
    if(dir != "") {
        struct stat st;
        if(dir[dir.length()] != '/') dir.append("/");
        string file = dir + cmdArg[0];
        //is file in dir?
        if(stat(file.c_str(), &st) == 0) {
            execvp(file.c_str(), cmdArg);
        }
    }
}
```